# buttons at the center of screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've created this xml file, and I want to center the two buttons at the middle of the screen instead of showing them at the very top of the screen

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/allow"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Allow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deny"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Deny" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

in both buttons to put in the center.

Comment: also known as `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Answer (score 1):

set gravity of Linear Layout.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
```